# How can I save a binary file to my project assets using project-lib python?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-studio, project-lib

The project lib documentation shows how to save a pandas dataframe to the project assets:

```
 # Import the lib
 from project_lib import Project
 project = Project(sc,"<ProjectId>", "<ProjectToken>")

 # let's assume you have the pandas DataFrame  pandas_df which contains the data
 # you want to save in your object storage as a csv file
 project.save_data("file_name.csv", pandas_df.to_csv())

 # the function returns a dict which contains the asset_id, bucket_name and file_name
 # upon successful saving of the data
```

However, if I have a local file ...

```
! wget url_to_binary_file
```

How can I then upload that file to the project’s assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to read the file as bytes.  Note that this will read the file into memory, don’t try this is you have a file that is larger than your available memory:

```
import io

filename = ‘thefilename’
with open(filename, 'rb') as z:
        data = io.BytesIO(z.read())
        project.save_data(
            filename, data, set_project_asset=True, overwrite=True
        )
```